# Effects of multiple moons on tides?

Tags: moons, tides

Hello I would like to ask what would be the effect of 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 moons on an earthlike planet? What would change? Consider may be a moon like our own and the other two of progressive smaller size? how would tides be effected? Any tsunami like timed periodical megawave or else? Volcanic activity? how would life be there?

Comment: Could you narrow it down? Right now we have too many scenarios to choose from.

Comment: The same effect on the sun occurs with all it's planets on Solar Cycles every 11 yrs or so due to Uranus with major cycles over much longer periods when more planets are in sync with Carrington Effect and Solar Flares.